# Initializer Error Using Netty 4 with RoboVM

Tags: java, netty, robovm

I am trying to simulate my existing project on ios via robovm.  The java project starts running, but quickly encounters a problem with Netty (4.0.25) libraries that I am using.  I am using the latest version of RoboVM.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher.get(TypeParameterMatcher.java:40)
    at io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher.find(TypeParameterMatcher.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.<init>(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:67)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.<init>(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:57)
    at com.MyGame.MyThread.<init>(MyThread.java:22)
    at com.MyGame.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:50)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(IOSGraphics.java:301)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(IOSGraphics.java:202)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.$cb$drawRect$(IOSGraphics.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:395)
    at com.MyGame.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1035)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.JdkLogger.log(JdkLogger.java:606)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.JdkLogger.info(JdkLogger.java:291)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:91)
    ... 13 more
```

Here is the line pointed to in Netty:

```
        } else if (PlatformDependent.hasJavassist()) {
```

It seems to me that Netty is trying use code that is unavailable in RoboVM.  This application runs fine in Android or Desktop versions, and the RoboVM version seems to run if I remove Netty references.  Any help on how to make the two coexist greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding <forceLinkClasses><pattern>java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file.